# Where do you usually go to get feedback when you have 2 different design variations?

Tags: feedback

If you are working in a startup, where do you go to get feedback?
If you are working in a large company, where do you go to get feedback?

Comment: SE isn't really the forum for these kinds of suggestions. Try jumping into the [UX Slack community](https://www.designerhangout.co/).

Comment: It is generally the User Testing which decides but it also depends on what stage the current process is.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should have access to users or at least pseduo-users (sales people, support staff, product owners, etc.) for feedback. Depending on how much specific domain knowledge your users need to have, you can use services like https://usabilityhub.com/preference-test or https://validately.com/ to gather feedback.

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend the following links:**

[How to get feedback on a startup idea?](https://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/how-to-get-feedback-on-a-startup-idea)

[Where is the best place to get feedback on a startup idea?](https://www.quora.com/Where-is-the-best-place-to-get-feedback-on-a-startup-idea)

[YCombinator](http://www.ycombinator.com/)